# Awk to match a string using the delimiters

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following in input.txt file.

```
<node>
<id>1</id>
<name>ServerA</name>
<type>Other</type>
</node>
<node>
<id>2</id>
<name>ServerB</name>
<type>Other</type>
</node>
```

Now i need to get following output.Only the name field.

ServerA
ServerB

Comment: That looks like XML. Why are you trying to process this using awk? And why is this question tagged `grep`?

Comment: Yeah this is an xml file. I have the hostname details in the name field. I have to extract these locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'Server' input.txt | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}' ORS=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's XML, then the document should be under a root node, such as `nodes`.

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>ServerA</name>
    <type>Other</type>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>ServerB</name>
    <type>Other</type>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

Afterwards, you can use either `xmllint` or Perl. I dislike the xmllint solution because it's such a pain to format the result; that's why I also provide a Perl answer.

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/nodes/node/name/text()' input.txt                                                                                            
ServerAServerB
$ perl -MXML::Simple -E "say foreach keys(XMLin('file.txt')->{node})"                                                            
ServerA
ServerB
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` alternative

```
$ sed -nr '/^<name>/s/<[^>]+>//gp' file

ServerA
ServerB
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on user3660575 post.

```
awk -v ORS=' ' -F'[<>]' '/Server/{print $3}END{printf "\n"}' file
ServerA ServerB
```